# How to add an object to existing List using Spring Mongo db?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

this is class A

```
@Document
class User{
private String id ;
private String name;
@Dbref
private List<Socity> Socitys;
}
```

and this is class Socity

```
@Document
class Socity{
private String id ;
private String name;
}
```

and this is the add user function

```
public User addUser(User user) {
    List<Socity> socity = new ArrayList<>();
    user.setsocitys (socity );
    return  userRepository.save(user);
}
```

I want to add a socity to an existing user
i try this but it doesn't work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx  = SpringApplication.run (App.class, args);
    SocityDao SDao = ctx.getBean(SocityDao .class);
    UserRepository userRepository = ctx.getBean(UserRepository.class);

    User u = userRepository.findOne("");
    Socity s = new Socity("soc1");
    SDao .addSocity(e);
    u.getSocitys().add(e);

}
```

this is the rest service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "up/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST ,produces = 
"application/json")
public User addSocityToUser(@RequestBody Socity, @PathVariable  String id) 
{

     return SocityDAO.addSocityToUser(e, id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end of your code add `userRepository.save(u)` to persist your changes to the DB.

As long as it as an ID (because it is a persisted object) it will be updated. if it has no ID it will be saved as a new object in the DB.

Comment: i get this error when i want to test rest service with postman 
"Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of  out of START_ARRAY token\n at

Comment: @O.o Its hard to answer without the full stack trace and seeing the code of the service. also, it is a different problem so its better if you open a new question with your current full code and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you **forget to save user**, after you add new socity. Please check my updates

```
@Document
public class Socity {
    private String id ;
    private String name;
}

@Document
public class User {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    @DBRef
    private List<Socity> socitys = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Then you **don't need to use your addUser() method**. When you want to add new user just use

```
 userRepository.save(user);
```

You also need two repositories

```
public interface SocityRepository extends MongoRepository<Socity, String> {
}
```

and

```
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    }
```

And what you need in the main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
ApplicationContext ctx  = SpringApplication.run (App.class, args);
UserRepository userRepository = ctx.getBean(UserRepository.class);
SocityRepository socityRepository = ctx.getBean(SocityRepository.class);

User u = userRepository.findOne("");
Socity s = socityRepository.save(new Socity("soc1"));
u.getSocitys().add(s);
userRepository.save(u);
```

}

Comment: my proble was that i forget to add userRepository.save(u)

Comment: i get this error when i want to test rest service with postman 
"Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of  out of START_ARRAY token\n at

Answer (score -1):

It is always better to Use the MongoTemplate to write an update Query and use Push function to add to a list.

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

 function(String id, Socity socity){
     Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(id));                  
     Update update = new Update();          
     update.push("Socitys", socity);
     mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, User.class);
}
```